# URL for Outlook Search

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

Is it possible to create a URL or hyperlink that opens up a mail search in Outlook 2010?

I often have e-mail messages associated with Outlook tasks, so I'd like to include in my task notes a URL that brings up an Outlook search for e-mail belonging to a specific category.

Comment: Why not add the email as an attachment to the task or create a new task based on an email?

Comment: There could be several e-mails associated with a task, prefer to search for them by category.

Comment: Thanks. You noted in that thread that you could do this in Outlook 2010. How?

Comment: You would be better off asking that as a whole new question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Microsoft OneNote installed, you could try a slightly different workflow. You CAN link to OneNote notes and when you export to OneNote from Outlook it creates a reverse link to the original.

Not perfect as I think you would need to export the emails into OneNote. You can create the task in OneNote and link back to Outlook or the other way around. Keeping things in OneNote and only using Outlook for the reminders and calendar integration is about the best workflow.

The advantage of this is that it will still work if you upgrade to Office 2013 whereas the search link will not. It also has the advantage that your OneNote notebooks can be shared with others over a network, DropBox, OneDrive or SharePoint (and others too). That sharing also allows access from multiple devices such as a smartphone or tablet or another PC.

Even better if several people are working on a task, they can all work on the same note in near realtime.

The downside is that you need OneNote which, until fairly recently, was not included in all versions of Office.